Remote-SSH extension from VSCode stuck in "Install and start server if needed"-step
I am trying to connect to a remote cluster via ssh using the "Remote-SSH"-extension from Visual Studio Code. This is the terminal output (before I cancelled it):
[19:19:10.641] Log Level: 2
[19:19:10.649] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+servername", attempt 1
[19:19:10.650] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false
[19:19:10.650] "remote.SSH.useExecServer": true
[19:19:10.650] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[19:19:10.650] "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {}
[19:19:10.650] "remote.SSH.path": undefined
[19:19:10.650] "remote.SSH.configFile": undefined
[19:19:10.650] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[19:19:10.650] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[19:19:10.651] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[19:19:10.651] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[19:19:10.651] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[19:19:10.651] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[19:19:10.651] "remote.SSH.loglevel": 2
[19:19:10.651] "remote.SSH.enableDynamicForwarding": true
[19:19:10.651] "remote.SSH.enableRemoteCommand": false
[19:19:10.651] "remote.SSH.serverPickPortsFromRange": {}
[19:19:10.651] "remote.SSH.serverInstallPath": {}
[19:19:10.655] VS Code version: 1.89.1
[19:19:10.655] Remote-SSH version: remote-ssh@0.110.1
[19:19:10.655] win32 x64
[19:19:10.660] SSH Resolver called for host: servername
[19:19:10.660] Setting up SSH remote "servername"
[19:19:10.664] Using commit id "dc96b837cf6bb4af9cd736aa3af08cf8279f7685" and quality "stable" for server
[19:19:10.667] Install and start server if needed

And this is whats been added when I cancel the last step.
[19:19:11.525] getPlatformForHost was canceled
[19:19:11.526] Resolver error: Error: Connecting was canceled
    at g.Canceled (c:\Users\name\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.110.1\out\extension.js:2:499377)
    at c:\Users\name\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.110.1\out\extension.js:2:579839
    at async t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\name\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.110.1\out\extension.js:2:583207)
    at async k (c:\Users\name\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.110.1\out\extension.js:2:576866)
    at async t.resolve (c:\Users\name\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.110.1\out\extension.js:2:580578)
    at async c:\Users\name\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.110.1\out\extension.js:2:846687
[19:19:11.531] ------

Does the "Install and start server if needed"-step just need hours to finish or what am I doing wrong?
I've already tried to just wait for around 30 minutes, but the "[timestamp] Install and start server if needed"-step was not finished. So I tried again and again.

Have you confirmed you can SSH into the cluster through command line?

yes, using cmd works fine. But I need to give a password. I am not sure if this is the problem here too

The getPlatformForHost error generally means VSCode doesn't know what it is trying to connect to and can't configure properly. As seen from this answer:

Add one key in your settings.json as below. Please remember to replace the $remote_server_name to yours.

"remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {
    "$remote_server_name": "linux"
}


I think I found out the problem: my config file seems to be wrong. It looks like this:
Host domain
HostName domain.com
User fabian
in cmd I would type "ssh fabian@domain.com". How should my /.ssh/config file look like?
